# Cordova Android app - cordova.js not found, but only in part of app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building my first android app with Cordova, and there's only a small part of the app that actually needs any of the Cordova/native functionality.

In the main page of the app, which is multiple screens set up as a carousel, everything works great, but there is one other page, and once in there, I can see that the attempt to load cordova.js is returning a 404, so navigator.app is undefined and I can't access any of the native functionality.

How can I 'help' the Cordova build process make the script available in all the places it's needed?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include cordova.js in your index.html file's headers -

```
<head>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: tabrindle - I do have `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in the headers of each page, and it loads fine in the main part of the app, but on the secondary page, it 404's when trying to load that file.   It appears that Cordova isn't working its magic during the building of the app, so it's looking for cordova.js in the www portion of my project.

Comment: Although I have never used this kind of architecture (multiple pages) It seems suspect to me that you are reincluding cordova each time. If you are loading in the subsequent pages by ajax and not actually fully refreshing the page, cordova should already be there.

Comment: I am actually loading a whole new page when the user goes into this other part of the app, so Cordova does need to be loaded.

I wound up working around this by changing "cordova.js" to "/android_assets/www/cordova.js" on the impacted page.

This seems like a fragile solution that's likely to break at some point in the future, so I'm still hoping to find a real fix, but for now it works.

Comment: This might be directory dependent. Does the secondary file live In the same directory as the index.html?

Comment: The secondary file lives in its own directory.  I suspected that might be the problem- if it is, can I tell Cordova to process subdirectories as well?

Comment: For src you have either absolute paths like you discovered, no path (just the name of the file) which assumes the same directory, or relative path, using folder names and ../  In your case the absolute path and no path src declarations are actually pointing to the same file as you don't have a copy of it. And as for it breaking, that absolute path for android hasn't changed in years but be careful if you want to use this for iOS. iOS uses a different directory structure. You may need to use something like ../../Cordova.js (relative path) for it to be compatible with both.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Cordova is properly installed in your project. You can install Cordova globally using the following command:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Ensure that the Cordova Android platform version is compatible with the Cordova version you are using. You can check and update the platform version using the following command:

```
cordova platform ls
cordova platform update android
```

Ensure that your index.html file contains the necessary script tags for Cordova. It should include the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Check for Typos or Case Sensitivity:
Verify that the path to cordova.js in your index.html file is correct, and that the file is located in the specified location.

Inspect the affected part of the app:
If the issue is occurring in a specific part of the app, carefully review the code in that section. Ensure that there are no errors or missing dependencies that could be preventing Cordova from loading properly.

Check Network Permissions:
If your app relies on external resources, ensure that the necessary network permissions are granted in the config.xml file:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Make sure that the Content Security Policy in your index.html file allows loading scripts. For testing purposes, you can temporarily set a permissive policy:

Sometimes, rebuilding the Cordova platform can resolve issues. Run the following commands:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Use the browser developer tools (if you are using Cordova in a browser) or Android device logs (if running on an Android device) to look for any additional error messages or warnings that might provide more information about the issue.

Ensure that all Cordova plugins used in your project are up-to-date. You can update them using:

```
cordova plugin update --all
```